# Filter based on condition and collect the object

Tags: java, lambda, filter, java-8, java-stream

In java 8, collect emp object based on some filter condition.

In main class:

```java
List<Emp> empList = Arrays.asList(
    new Emp("aaa", language1), 
    new Emp("cc", language2),
    new Emp("bb", language3), 
    new Emp("dd", language3)
);

empList.stream()
    .flatMap(s->s.getLanguage().stream())
    .filter(s->s.equals("java"))
    .forEach(System.out::println); //Here just i am printing.
```

Actually I need to collect `new List<EMP>`.

How to collect emp object that are all have language "java". How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should not use `flatMap` if you want to collect `Emp` objects in the end because it will change every element to something else and it can be quite hard to map them back.

You should put all your logic in a `filter`: "keep the `Emp` object if `getLanguage` contains `"java"`".

```
empList.stream()
    .filter(x->x.getLanguage().contains("java"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this:

```java
List<Object> optionMetas = new ArrayList<>();
Map<Long, Object> optionIdMetaMap_ = optionMetas.stream()
        .filter(option -> option.getXX() || option.getXXX().equal("java"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Object::getKEY, item -> item));
```

Add your relevant condition in [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-).

Answer (score 1):

You can process the *current* list using [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method that accepts a filter [`predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html):

```java
empList.removeIf(e -> !e.getLanguage().equals("java"));
```

Or you can copy the *current* list to *another* list and do the same.