# Pulling only certain objects from an array based on the values of another array of strings

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I am working on an *android project* in *java*. I have an array of objects that looks like this

```
Agenda = [{id: 1, sessionName: Some name, sessionLocation: Some place},
         {id: 2, sessionName: Some name, sessionLocation: Some place},
         {id: 3, sessionName: Some name, sessionLocation: Some place}]
```

I also have an array of strings that is dynamic, so it can have several values... looks like this:

```
sessionID = {1, 3}
```

How can I check for these sessionIDs within the "id" field in the Agenda array and pull only these objects where the ids match into a new array.

Note:

- This is java not javascript
- "id" in the Agenda array objects is an
  int
- sessionID array is an array of string

I tried several examples but none of them worked!

Comment: filter is your friend - take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47787247/java-8-stream-api-filter-based-on-condition-and-collect-the-object

Comment: Hi @user2637293, can you give me a update to see if this solves.

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED] Example for Arraylist:

If you are using Java 8, consider the following setup:

```
List<Agenda> agenda = new ArrayList<Agenda>();
agenda.add(new Agenda(1));
agenda.add(new Agenda(2));
agenda.add(new Agenda(3));

String[] sessionID = new String[] {"1", "3"};
```

You can do:

```
List<Agenda> agendaFiltered = agenda.stream()
        .filter(agendaObj -> Arrays.binarySearch(sessionID, Integer.toString(agendaObj.getId())) >= 0)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then if you run:

```
agendaFiltered.forEach(System.out::println);
```

It will print only:

```
Agenda{id=1}
Agenda{id=3}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! My Agenda is an ArrayList. Will this example still work?

Comment: updated @user11527839. As you were saying array, I did it with array. Now Agenda is a List.

Comment: hi @user11527839 can you accept it this solves the issue, thanks.

Comment: The naming is little bit confusing. .filter() runs on objects, not filters.
List<Agenda> agendaFiltered = agenda.stream()
            .filter(agendaObj -> sessionIdsArray.contains(agendaObj.id))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());